# Unity 5: Stays slow after code runs

Tags: c#, unity, water

Hi guys :) I have just tweaked the FPSController Script so that when you are below 6y, you are slower and gravity is a little weaker. This is to simulate underwater effects, but when you come out of the water, the effects are still applied.

Code:

```
if ((transform.position.y < waterLevel) != isUnderwater) {
    isUnderwater = transform.position.y < waterLevel;
    m_WalkSpeed = 3;
    m_RunSpeed = 6;
    m_JumpSpeed = 12;
}
```

This is run in the `void Update()` void so that it checks for it every frame.

Does someone have a solution so when you come out of the water, the original movement is used? Thanks.

EDIT: Some people have been getting confused, so I'll explain. I'm running this `if(){}` statement in `public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour`. I did not make my own class, I used their `void Update()` instead of making my own. So, any variables in that class cannot be used outside.

Comment: Store the original values in class variables before changing them when you go underwater?

Comment: Those variables are already used in the script and are defined public.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you want to store the variables before changing them. And you change them only when the state change, i.e. when you go from over the water to under the water, and from under the water to over the water. You'll probably want to set these values from the editor. You can add the values for the underwater movement variables as class variables:

Add to the class `public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour`:

```
// My Mod start
[SerializeField] private float m_waterLevel;

[SerializeField] private float m_underWaterWalkSpeed;
[SerializeField] private float m_underWaterRunSpeed ;
[SerializeField] private float m_underWaterJumpSpeed;

private float m_initialWalkSpeed;
private float m_initialRunSpeed;
private float m_initialJumpSpeed;

private bool m_isUnderwater;
// My Mod end
```

Add to the method `private void Update()`:

```
// My Mod start
if ((transform.position.y < m_waterLevel) && !m_isUnderwater) {
  // Switch state -> going from over the water to under the water

  // store the variables
  m_initialWalkSpeed  = m_WalkSpeed;
  m_initialRunSpeed   = m_RunSpeed ;
  m_initialJumpSpeed  = m_JumpSpeed;

  // update the state
  m_isUnderwater = true;
  m_WalkSpeed = m_underWaterWalkSpeed;
  m_RunSpeed  = m_underWaterRunSpeed ;
  m_JumpSpeed = m_underWaterJumpSpeed;
}
else if ( m_isUnderwater && transform.position.y > m_waterLevel ){
  // Switch state -> going from under the water to over the water

  // update the state: reset the variables
  m_isUnderwater = false;
  m_WalkSpeed = m_initialWalkSpeed;
  m_RunSpeed  = m_initialRunSpeed ;
  m_JumpSpeed = m_initialJumpSpeed;
}
// My Mod end
```

Add at the end of the method `private void Start()`:

```
// My Mod start
if ( transform.position.y < m_waterLevel ) {
  // store the variables
  m_initialWalkSpeed  = m_WalkSpeed;
  m_initialRunSpeed   = m_RunSpeed ;
  m_initialJumpSpeed  = m_JumpSpeed;

  // update the state
  m_isUnderwater = true;
  m_WalkSpeed = m_underWaterWalkSpeed;
  m_RunSpeed  = m_underWaterRunSpeed ;
  m_JumpSpeed = m_underWaterJumpSpeed;
}
else {
  m_isUnderwater = false;
}
// My Mod end
```

Comment: Makes sense, I tried using it but there are no waterLevel or isUnderwater variables

Comment: I also tried using the latter code, but still it does not have the variables defined in the class

Comment: @JJP you realize that these variables (`waterLevel` and `isUnderwater`) were originally in your code? I assumed that they were in _your_ class since you did not provide more information.

Comment: Yes but I simply said it was run in the Update() void. I was meaning inside the original class. But since there is a different class now, those variables don't apply.

Comment: @JJP Then please update the question with the class that you have written instead of only a small snippet. I have update my answer, added an important call on the second example.

Comment: @JJP This new edit should do what you need. I've tried it in Unity.

Comment: I just have one question, the answer is probably really simple. Where do I customize the numbers on how slow or fast you move underwater?

Comment: They should appear as values you can set in the editor, at the same place where you change other values (Run Speed, Walk Speed, Jump Speed, etc.). The fact that they are declared as `[SerializeField] private` makes them show in the editor.

Comment: :/ theyre not showing up. only the original settings (Walk Speed, Run Speed) are showing, but not the underwater ones

Comment: nevermind i see them